# Is there a way to lazy-init a costly field in a specific constructor?

Tags: kotlin, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

I have a data class I want to populate, where in one constructor I have the data already, and in another I would like to fetch it only when it is required, which is rare.

A sample code would be:

```
data class Source1(val str1: String)
data class Source2(val str2: String)

data class DTO(val data1: String, val data2: String) {
    // ctor which does not need laziness
    constructor(source1: Source1) : this(
        data1 = source1.str1,
        data2 = source1.str1
    )

    // ctor which needs costly data
    constructor(source2: Source2, costlyData: String) : this(
        data1 = source2.str2,
        data2 = costlyData
    )
}

fun demo() {
    val source1 = Source1("some str - 1")
    DTO(source1)

    val source2 = Source2("some str - 2")
    val costlyData: String = costlyOperation() // this is the operation I'd like to execute lazily
    DTO(source2, costlyData)
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the easiest way would be to accept a function as a constructor parameter, something like this:

```
class DTO(provider:()->String){
    constructor(data: String):this({data})

    val data by lazy{ provider()}
}
```

So you can use it in both ways:

```
val eager = DTO("some str - 1")
val lazy = DTO(::costlyOperation)
```

A bit nicer way is to have a `Source` abstraction with different implementations for providing a constant value and performing an operation. But the overall idea would be the same.

Although I wouldn't call this DTO anymore and it loses its data class capabilities regarding the content.